# Consume a REST service from a C#/XAML Metro App?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, microsoft-metro

I'm learning how to build C#/XAML metro apps in Windows 8 and I was wondering if there's a way to call RESTful services using the framework? I was able to with a JS/HTML5 app, but I am wanting to do this from C#/XAML.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [System.Net.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) and [HttpRequestMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159020%28v=vs.110%29).

Here's a writeup for [Consuming Json Data in WinRT](http://www.bartlannoeye.be/blog/consuming-json-data-in-winrt)

Basically, it's used like:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = "http://yourservice.com/some/resource";
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
return response.Content.ReadAsString();
```

If you need to modify the request or get called during the pipeline of execution (add things like headers) you can use [HttpMessageHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler.aspx).

Here's another related post asking about headers with WinRT:

[Using HttpRequestHeaders in WinRT & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882244/using-httprequestheaders-in-winrt-c-sharp)

Comment: System.Net.HttpClient is available in framework 4.5...how can i do this in framework 4?